# If quotient space $X/Y$ is complete then $X$ is complete

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, quotient-spaces

It is well-known that if $X$ is a Banach space and $Y$ is a closed subspace then $X /Y$ with quotient norm
$$ \| [x] \|_{X/Y} = \inf_{y \in Y} \| x-y \| $$
is a Banach space.

I am trying to prove the converse:

*Let $X$ be a normed space, $Y$ its closed subspace which is complete. If $X/Y$ is complete spce, then $X$ is complete.*

My attempts was to equivalently prove that $X$ is not complete and conclude that $X/Y$ cannot be complete. Assume that there exists sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ which is Cauchy, but not convergent. Using the inequality 
$$ \| [x_n ] \|_{X/Y} \leq \| x \|_X $$
we obtain that sequence $ ([x_n])$ is Cauchy in $X/Y$. Next step, that I cant make would be to prove that it is not convergent, or that this allows us to construct non-convergent Cauchy sequence.

I also proved that $Y$ has to be complete, I have a counterexample otherwise. So this fact has to be used somehow.

Note that this is an exercise for first weeks of introductory functional analysis course, so I can't use any advanced techniques.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since $(x_n)$ is Cauchy then $([x_n])$ is Cauchy. Therefore it converges, say $[x_n]\to [z]$ in $X/Y$.

By the definition of the norm, for every $m\in\mathbb{N}$ you can find $n_m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $y_m\in Y$ such that $$\left\|{x_{n_m}-z-y_m}\right\|<\frac{1}{m}.$$

Then prove $(y_m)$ is Cauchy, so it converges, and also does $(x_{n_m})$.

Comment: @wroobell How did you prove that $(y_m)$ is Cauchy?

Comment: Yes why is that sequence cauchy? I'm also stuck here. Please help.

Comment: $(y_m)$ is Cauchy because, for all $p, q \in \Bbb N$, 
$$ \|y_p - y_q\|  \le \|x_{n_p} - z - y_p\| +\|x_{n_p} - x_{n_q}\| +  \|x_{n_q} - z - y_q\| \leq \frac{1}{p} + \|x_{n_p} - x_{n_q}\| + \frac{1}{q}$$
and $(x_{n_m})$ is Cauchy ( because  $(x_{n_m})$ is a sub-sequence of $(x_n)$ ).

Comment: @Ramiro How does $(x_{n_m})$ being Cauchy and a subsequence of $(x_n)$ imply that $X$ is complete though? Wouldn't we need to prove that the Cauchy sequence $(x_n)\in X$ converges to a limit in $X$? I thought showing the subsequence converges would only show that $X$ is compact. Can't see what I'm missing here.

Comment: @DoubleV By my previous comment, it proves that $(y_m)$ is Cauchy in $Y$. Since $Y$ is complete, $(y_m)$ converges. So $(x_{n_m})$ converges. Since $(x_n)$ is Cauchy and it has a convergent sub-sequence, $(x_n)$ itself converges. So $X$ is complete.

Comment: @Ramiro Thank you for reclarifying that point you already made. It just went over my head.

Comment: What about the definition of the norm allows us to state that for every $m\in\mathbb{N}$ you can find $n_m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $y_m\in Y$ such that
$\left\|{x_{n_m}-z-y_m}\right\|<\frac{1}{m}.$?